# How to setup mqtt client to listen to a topic permanently?

Tags: graphql, mqtt

I'm currently working on a project that is a sort of an extension to an existing project.

**Existing Project:**

A product that is already there and has a pub/sub system of its own. It uses GraphQL.

Let's take an example.

- There's a group (GROUP_1) and some users are a part of that group.
- Let's say user A calls a mutation, the other users' sessions subscribed to that mutation get an update regarding the same(that A made these changes). The changes are reflected in their frontend accordingly.

**What do we need?**

- Instead of user A making the change, we want to update when a third party service notifies us to make the change.
- The thing is that the third-party service uses MQTT protocol and will give us a topic (for GROUP_1) to which it will publish the messages and we need to subscribe to it. Upon receiving the message if the message satisfies our condition we will call the mutation on behalf of the user the message specifies.

**Problem**

- So we need the client to listen to that topic forever.
- And there can be an addition to the topics provided. New groups can be added in the future. So we will have different topics for different groups(GROUP_1, GROUP_2, etc)

**Research that I did**

To have a client that listens to a topic permanently and we can add to that client new topics as we generate new GROUPS.
And then let this client update the GraphQL API eventually reflecting changes in the session of the users in that GROUP.
I think that's not the way MQTT should be used, we should make changes in the existing project but that is not in our hands as of now.

**Constraint**

We can't change the existing workflow of GraphQL mutation and subscription that the existing project has.

**Questions**

- Is there a better approach to do this with the given constraint?
- If not then how should we go about creating a client that listens permanently. Shall we have a server that's up for the same or is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm not understanding your post, but the solution seems pretty simple: Create a new client that subscribes to what the "third party service" publishes to, and then publish to the Topic that the existing clients subscribe to, all the info that was passed in by the 3rd party.  The beauty of a Pub/Sub architecture is that adding functionality to an existing system is done by just adding a new set of clients...subscribers, publishers, or both.  The existing system doesn't have to change at all, if you can reuse the existing Topics and data formats.  So you create a "Proxy" that takes in the new info, and publishes out in the old format.